# bash remove duplicate of key values with preserving order

Tags: bash, awk

I have 2 files which I need to combine and generate a 3rd file. Please find the sample below,

File 1

```
xab=p11
aab=p12
aac=p23
xac=p15
yab=p16
```

File 2

```
aab=p17
xac=p25
yyc=p22
```

I would like to preserve the order of the first file and append the second file. The result should be:

File 3

```
xab=p11
aab=p17
aac=p23
xac=p25
yab=p16
yyc=p22
```

I tried many ways, but not able to get a simpler, easy to understandable solution. The one I found in StackOverflow was working, but it is hard to understand and explain to a third person. The solution I found was

```
cat en_us.txt en_US2.txt | tr -s '\n' | awk -F= '!a[$1]{b[++i]=$1} {a[$1]=$0;} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){print a[b[j]]}}'
```

Can anyone try this and get a readable solution (probably one not using `awk`)

Comment: Do you want to preserve the order in the second file as well?

Comment: Yes, and I would like to have a solution that does not use complex awk / sed , so that it is easily explainable to a non linux person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="=" }
{ key=$1; val=$2 }
NR==FNR {
    keys[++numKeys] = key
    key2val[key] = val
    next
}
{
    if ( key in key2val ) {
        val = key2val[key]
        delete key2val[key]
    }
    print key, val
}
END {
    for (keyNr=1; keyNr<=numKeys; keyNr++) {
        key = keys[keyNr]
        if (key in key2val) {
            print key, key2val[key]
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
xab=p11
aab=p17
aac=p23
xac=p25
yab=p16
yyc=p22
```

Answer (score 9):

Another `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F'=' '{ if($1 in b) a[b[$1]]=$0;
               else{a[++i]=$0; b[$1]=i} }
             END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++) print a[j]}' f1 f2
xab=p11
aab=p17
aac=p23
xac=p25
yab=p16
yyc=p22
```

- Note that both files are processed together as single input here, no `NR==FNR` stuff
- `else{a[++i]=$0; b[$1]=i}` this code is executed if first column isn't seen before

  - `a[++i]=$0` this saves the line content based on numerical key
  - `b[$1]=i` this array helps to get the numerical key number based on first column
- `if($1 in b) a[b[$1]]=$0` this is executed when first column already exists

  - `a[b[$1]]=$0` this will update the earlier entry
- `END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++) print a[j]}` print the array content after all input lines have been processed

With `ruby`, it is easier as the insertion order is retained by default.

```
$ ruby -F'=' -lane 'BEGIN{h={}}; h[$F[0]]=$_; END{puts h.values}' f1 f2
xab=p11
aab=p17
aac=p23
xac=p25
yab=p16
yyc=p22
```

- `BEGIN{h={}};` assign empty `hash` to variable `h`
- `h[$F[0]]=$_` save contents of input line based on first field
- `puts h.values` print values of each `hash` key

You can save some space by using `h[$F[0]]=$F[1]` and then `END{h.each_key{|k| puts "#{k}=#{h[k]}"}}`

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** In case you want to maintain the order of both the Input_file(s) then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="="
}
FNR==NR{
  if(!($1 in d)){
    e[++count]=$1
  }
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
{
  print $1,($1 in a?a[$1]:$2)
  c[$1]
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(!(e[i] in c)){ print e[i],a[e[i]] }
  }
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples(this will not take care of order of Input_file2 lines).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS="="
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$2
  next
}
{
  print $1,($1 in a?a[$1]:$2)
  c[$1]
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(!(i in c)){
      print i,a[i]
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file2  Input_file1
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk` command:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   FS=OFS="="
}
FNR == NR {
   a[$1] = $2
   next
}
$1 in a {
   $2 = a[$1]
   delete a[$1]
}
1
END {
   for (i in a)
      print i, a[i]
}' file2 file1
```

```
xab=p11
aab=p17
aac=p23
xac=p25
yab=p16
yyc=p22
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `ruby` hashes [maintain insertion order](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html), you can just maintain a hash of the keys and update that key if a new value is seen:

```
ruby -F= -ane 'BEGIN{h=Hash.new()}
        h[$F[0]]=$F[1].rstrip
        END{h.map{|l| puts l.join("=")}}' f1.txt f2.txt
```

Prints:

```
xab=p11
aab=p17
aac=p23
xac=p25
yab=p16
yyc=p22
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the original request was for something more readable than awk, here are a few [Tcl](https://www.tcl-lang.org/) solutions.

1. A verbose version written for clarity.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env tclsh
    package require fileutil
    foreach file $argv {
        fileutil::foreachLine line $file {
            lassign [split $line =] key value
            dict set data $key $value
        }
    }
    dict for {key value} $data {
        puts $key=$value
    }
```

The only two lines that might not seem obvious are:

- `lassign` which takes the list in its first argument and creates variables with the names of its remaining arguments (variable destructuring).
- `dict set` which adds a new entry to a dictionary (hash map / associative array) named `data` with the given key/value pair. Tcl will automatically create nonexistent variables the first time they are assigned to.

Tcl dictionaries preserve the insertion order (similar to Ruby as mentioned in other answers).

2. A slightly more idiomatic version.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env tclsh
    package require fileutil
    foreach file $argv {
        fileutil::foreachLine line $file {
            dict set data {*}[split $line =]
        }
    }
    dict for {k v} $data {puts $k=$v}
```

The confusing line here uses the splat operator `{*}` which expands (explodes) a list as individual arguments, thus saving us the need to create temporary variables to hold the key/value pairs.

3. [Owh](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/owh+-+a+fileless+tclsh), an awk-ish version.

```
cat f1 f2 | owh '' 'dict set data {*}[split $0 =]' 'dict for {k v} $data {puts $k=$v}'
```

- It's named owh in homage to awk, for the names Ousterhout (original creator of Tcl), Welch and Hobbs, two prolific contributors to early Tcl.
- It takes three scripts: BEGIN, each-line, and END (without the need to name them so).
- Like awk, it uses `$0` to represent the whole input line.

4. Another Tcl Awk, [Tawk](https://github.com/shawnw/tawk).

```
tawk -F = 'line {dict set data $F(1) $F(2)}; END {dict for {k v} $data {puts $k=$v}}' f1 f2
```

- Which represents Awk's `$1` as `$F(1)`.

and a whole-line preserving version (if formatting is more complicated to reproduce than the simple x=y here):

```
tawk -F = 'line {dict set data $F(1) $F(0)}; END {puts [join [dict values $data] \n]}' f1 f2
```

Where:

- `$F(0)` is the whole input line.
- The `dict values` command returns a list of items like `xab=p11` , `aab=p17` , ...
- Tcl doesn't need to quote string values like the `\n` (newline) in the `join` command.