# How do I get the values of the created array present in file1 and not in file2 with awk?

Tags: shell, awk

Suppose file1 has contents:

```
1=apple
2=mango
3=banana
4=litchi 
7=papaya
```

and file2:

```
1=apple
2=banana
3=grapes

4=kiwi
5=orange
6=peach
```

and I need the final output as:

```
1=apple
2=mango
3=banana

4=litchi
7=papaya
5=orange
6=peach
```

Create an associative array for file 1 and compare the array element in file2 but how can I get the array for the lines that are in file1 and absent in file2.

With this code:

```
awk -F"=" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next;}
{ 
        if ($1 in a && $1)
                print a[$1]
        else if(!$1)
                print
        else
                print $1"="$NF
}' file1 file2


Output
--------
1=apple
2=mango
3=banana

4=litchi
5=orange
6=peach
```

I am able to get till key 6, no luck getting key 7.

If I add this piece with the condition:

```
...
    else if(!($1 in a)){ for (i in a) {
                    print a[i]}}
...
```

I get the output as:

```
1=apple
2=mango
3=banana

4=litchi
3=banana
2=mango
1=apple
4=litchi
7=papaya
3=banana
2=mango
1=apple
4=litchi
7=papaya
```

Kindly, help me to figure out the correct condition.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63954081/bash-remove-duplicate-of-key-values-with-preserving-order would qualify as duplicate, except for the empty line.. not sure about the logic you are following to preserve that empty line

Comment: @Sundeep, I have many client-specific properties file that is needed to be replaced in the original file and also some properties that are to be printed as it is, as in the first file. Space is required to preserve the readability. I tried with your posted link, unfortunately, it did not give me the expected result, and also that is quite complex. I only needed a condition where I can check for elements that are in the array and not in fields in the second file.

Comment: "*How can I get [...] the lines that are in file1 and **absent** in file2?*" Why is `1=apple` in your desired output?

Comment: @Cyrus, 1=apple is from the file1.

Comment: Do you need to find and output the blank lines too? Why?

Comment: It's not at all clear what logic you want to employ to get the output you say you want and in [a comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65548289/how-do-i-get-the-values-of-the-created-array-present-in-file1-and-not-in-file2-w#comment115892959_65549296) you say piping other output to `sort` gets you the output you want but that can't possibly produce the output shown in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { 
    FS=OFS="="          # field separator
}
NR==FNR {               # process file1
    a[$1]=$0            # index on first field
    b[$1]               # this is used for seen ones
    next
}
{                       # process file2
    if($1 in a) {       # if first field found in file1
        print a[$1]     # print that instead
        delete b[$1]    # delete from b to mark it as seen
    } else 
        print $0        # print file2 entry if was not in file1
}
END {                   # in the end
    for(i in b)         # the ones from file1 not in file2
        print a[i]      # output
}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
1=apple
2=mango
3=banana

4=litchi 
5=orange
6=peach
7=papaya
```

Comment: Thanks! This gives me the desired result but I am unable to keep up with the order, kindly share an update if that can be preserved as well.

Comment: The empty line is the problem, getting that in the correct place requires processing `file1` and then `file2` which then causes `7=papaya`  to be outputed after `file2`. Can't think of a way for the exact output without some preselected output order.

Comment: Thanks, James. I would rather go with the result without installing any additional software.

Comment: Found a workaround, by piping the output to the sort command. I was purely looking into awk but this would work for now. Thanks, James.

Comment: How could piping the output to `sort` possibly produce the output you asked for with a blank line in the middle of the output and a line starting with `7` coming before a line starting with `5`??? This is an extremely confusing question....

Comment: @James, why do you keep a separate `b` array instead of `delete a[$1]`?

Comment: @glennjackman I made it to support two and more instances of  `$2`.

Comment: Buy you're using the same key $1

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry, I meant `$1` (there was just a `$2` related question elsewhere).

Comment: @EdMorton, This example is just a demonstration of my actual use case. I got my output sorted by piping. That's what I mentioned there. I have many client-specific property files and that also contains information about the different environments. eg.  ```dev.abc = ...    staging.abc= ...   prod.abc=...```   These are separated by blank lines. and while printing the array in the awk END section, the properties in file1 were getting printed without their respective sections which would get difficult to read at times of debugging. Hope this eases your confusion.

Comment: @EdMorton, Ideally I would want the output from the awk command only, but this is a workaround by using sort, which helped in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to give correct results, for this data, but I am asking meself if this will hold up in all situations..... :

```
awk -F"=" 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0;next;}
{
        if(!($1 in a)){ for (i in a) {
                if(i>FNR) print a[i]}}
        if ($1 in a && $1)
                print a[$1]
        else if(!$1)
                print
        else
                print $1"="$NF
}' file1 file2
```

output:

```
1=apple
2=mango
3=banana
7=papaya

4=litchi
7=papaya
5=orange
6=peach
```

Comment: Although the papaya example worked fine but did not hold true for my use case. Thanks Luuk.